# Different mean symbols on violin plots using facet_grid

Tags: shapes, mean, symbols

I would like  to have the triangle mean symbol changed to open on the green violin plots when using facet_grid. Using ggplot2 I can get this on the single graphs (like the one below) by including 'shape=c(19, 2)' in stat_summary, and would like to get the grid to look like this too.

[image: Graph with differnt mean symbols]

Here is a sample of the data I used

[image: Status Day0 Day14 Day28 Day42 Day56 Day70 Day84 Day98 PPID 1695 156 333 248 845 694 85 1777 PPID 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 PPID 0 0 0 0 0 0 201 0 PPID 652 0 42 39 100 384 405 549 Control 0 74 0 117 309 0 165 208 Control 1440 0 0 39 40 0 41 127 Control 2865 0 0 82 39 420 79 85 Control 165 0 0 0 0 78 198 42]

This is the code I used to organise the data and labels. With the shape code included with stat_summary, it won't return a graph and I've not managed to find a solution for this

```
        CombFEC <- Chp2FEC1 %>% gather(Day, EPG, 2:9)

    Dayorder <- CombFEC                            
Dayorder$Day <- factor(Dayorder$Day,     
                       levels = c("Day0", "Day14", "Day28", 
                                  "Day42", "Day56", "Day70",
                                  "Day84", "Day98")) 
glimpse(Dayorder)

FEC.labs <- c(Day0 = "Day 0", Day14 = "Day 14", Day28 = "Day 28",
              Day42 = "Day 42", Day56 = "Day 56", Day70 ="Day 70",
              Day84 = "Day 84", Day98 = "Day 98")
FEC.labs

    FEC3 <- ggplot(Dayorder, aes(x=Status, y=EPG, fill=Status, shape=Status)) +
  geom_violin(width=1.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#56B4E9", "#009E73"))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(), 
              aes(colour = Status),
              cex = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0066CC", "#003300"))+
  ylab("Log (eggs per gram +1)") +
  scale_y_log10()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=40))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=50))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

FEC4 <- FEC3 +  facet_grid(. ~ Day, switch = "both", labeller = labeller(Day = FEC.labs, label_wrap_gen(20)))+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect( fill="#FFFFFF", size=1.5, linetype="blank"))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=40))

FEC4 + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, mult=1, 
                    geom="pointrange", shape=c(19, 2), size = 2)
```

Without including shape in the stat_summary, I get this graph but I would like to have open triangle mean points on the green plots.

[image: Facet_grid with filled triangle mean points. I would like to have open triangle mean points]

Any advise on finding a solution would be very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but you could repeat the vector containing the information on the shapes by the number of levels that you have for the variable you use for faceting (`Day`). The `shape` argument of `stat_summary()` could look like this: `shape = rep(c(19, 2), length(unique(CombFEC$Day)))`.

The following code generates a plot similar to yours but with open triangles for the means of the "PPID" group:

```r
# load libraries
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# get your data sample
Chp2FEC1 <- structure(list(Status = c("PPID", "PPID", "PPID", "PPID", "Control",
                                      "Control", "Control", "Control"),
                           Day0 = c(1695, 0, 0, 652, 0,1440, 2865, 165),
                           Day14 = c(156, 0, 0, 0, 74, 0, 0, 0),
                           Day28 = c(333, 0, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                           Day42 = c(248, 0, 0, 39, 117, 39, 82,0),
                           Day56 = c(845, 0, 0, 100, 309, 40, 39, 0),
                           Day70 = c(694,0, 0, 384, 0, 0, 420, 78),
                           Day84 = c(85, 0, 201, 405, 165, 41, 79, 198),
                           Day98 = c(1777, 40, 0, 549, 208, 127, 85, 42)),
                      row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

# transform to long format
CombFEC2 <- pivot_longer(data = Chp2FEC1,
                         cols = starts_with("Day"),
                         names_to = "Day")

# avoid scientific notion in plots
options(scipen = 999)

# plot
ggplot(data = CombFEC, aes(x = Status, y = EPG+1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Day, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Status)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Status), width = .2, height = 0) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl,
               shape = rep(c(19, 2), length(unique(CombFEC$Day)))) +
  scale_y_log10(name = "Log (eggs per gram +1)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#009E73")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0066CC", "#003300")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I prefer the bold triangle to the one I had.